# Photos taken via Camera2 targeting Android 10 do not include exif data

Tags: android, android-camera, android-10.0

After targeting Android 10, all photos taken- even on devices running pre-Android 10- do not include any location exif data.  This is while including the ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION permission, as well as ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

The documentation all includes information about accessing photos taken outside of your application, but I see no mention of photos taken within your application.  The exif values are all empty unless manually set from the last known location.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and if so, any ideas for how to resolve it?

Comment: Is the location information written to the media store instead?

Comment: "all photos taken- even on devices running pre-Android 10- do not include any location exif data" -- I would be surprised if it behaved otherwise. Where in the documentation does it state that Camera2 is supposed to store location data in EXIF automatically? "any ideas for how to resolve it?" -- set them manually.

Comment: honestly I was surprised that it was set automatically before.  If setting it manually is the way to go, that sounds fine to me.